# Configurable Products Super product attribute prices don't add on

Tags: configurable-product, product-attribute

Magento CE 1.7.02. I have a problem with configurable product pricing. I think I understand how it's supposed to work (config product price + super attribute price). I have several configurable products that work fine (about 50). However, I noticed the other day that one was not working and have now found two more not working.
They display correctly, and the dropdowns are there to select the options, showing the correct price differences. However, when the required option is selected, the price does not add on, the quantity does not increment, and the checkout does not work. The page is not locked, but nothing happens. You can select another option for the same base configurable product, but they all do the same thing.
I have flushed all caches, re-indexed, deleted these products and recreated - same thing. I cannot re-create a configurable product that works, EXCEPT if I use the attributes of one of the other products that DOES work. SO I think it is related to the attributes, but I have been thru all the attribute settings comparing the ones that work to those that don't. No differences I can see. I stumped. What do I do now? 
I'm a Magento beginner, and no programmer, so if anyone can help I'd really appreciate it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, please check for any JavaScript errors in the developer console. Second, which attributes are you using to create your configurable products?

In addition, do you by any chance use tier prices for your configurable products? If so, handling tier prices for configurable products does not work in vanilla Magento. Have a look here for more information on this matter: https://www.kerstner.at/en/2015/07/set-tier-prices-for-product-variants-of-configurable-products-in-magento/

When you say the checkout does not work, what do you mean exactly by that? Do you see error messages or does the price not match your settings?

Comment: Thanks for your response. No JavaScript errors in the console.log, just one about uni fileuploader. No tier prices. Also the checkout. I mean if you press the checkout button, the button "clicks" like normal, but no response at all. Further investigations show I can create a new configurable product using the attribute set and attributes of one of the other products that works. I cannot create new attribute, or attribute set that works with a new product. So at this point it seems to be to do with the attribute, or attribute set.